# Is Dirac neutrino ruled out by current experimental observation?

Tags: mass, fermions, dirac-equation, neutrinos, majorana-fermions

I have read the neutrino mass problem. The unnatural smallness of neutrino mass implies the existence of new physics so the seesaw mechanism is introduced to solve this theoretical problem.

I understand that Dirac neutrino has only the problem of its origin, however, is the possibility that neutrinos are Dirac particle ruled out by the current experimental observation?

Comment: No option, Dirac or Majorana, has been confirmed or ruled out by direct experiment. But there are lots of reasons for theory to prefer considering options beyond strict Dirac neutrinos.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not ruled out. As far as I am aware, the only experiments attempting to prove whether the neutrino is Majorana or Dirac are [neutrinoless double beta decay (wiki link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrinoless_double_beta_decay) experiments. These experiments try to detect a decay of radioactive nuclei which violates lepton number conservation and therefore prove that the neutrino is its own antiparticle (that it's Majorana). This decay is obviously impossible if the neutrino is a Dirac particle, so if this decay was observed it would immediately rule out Dirac neutrinos.

According to [this article (Neutrinoless double beta decay)](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/17/11/115010), the expected lifetime of neutrinoless double beta decay is $\sim10^{27}$ years. That's a very rough estimate, and it assumes a "normal heirarchy" ([neutrino mass hierarchy wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_mass_hierarchy)). That is - that the neutrino masses work the same way as other standard model particles (see quark masses and electron/muon/tau masses) - the three generations of particles have a roughy geometric increase in their mass.

Current neutrinoless double beta decay experiments have bounds around $10^{25}$ years. So we are about two orders of magnitude from ruling out/in the most reasonable Majorana neutrino models (and therefore two orders of magnitude from proving whether or not the neutrino is a Dirac particle).